# Provider data is becoming null after app is backgrounded

Tags: flutter, dart

I am noticing that **dataLength** variable of my **User** object becomes null after my app is backgrounded. It works perfectly across all the widgets that uses it when the variable is initially set. But once I background the app and bring it back to the foreground it becomes null until the stream rebuilds. Can anyone help out, thanks!

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myUserData = Provider.of<MyUser>(context, listen: false);
    final User myUser = myUserData.getUser();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
        stream: _stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty) {
            myUser.results = 0;
            return Container();
          } else {
           List<Data> myDataList = [];
             snapshot.data.docs.forEach(
              (element) async {
                Data myData = Data.fromMap(element.data());
                myDataList.add(myData);
                             })
           myUser.dataLength = myDataList.length;
              },...

class MyUser with ChangeNotifier {
  User _myUser = User(
  );

  User getUser() {
    return _myUser;
  }...

class User {
    int? dataLength;

  User({
    this.dataLength,
  });...
```

Comment: Is that on a device or on desktop? There is no such thing as "background" on devices, when your app "goes into the background", the system basically removes it and starts over when you activate it again.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This is on mobile devices. When I mean background, it's not necessarily killing the app but switching to, for example, another app. The moment the app is switched back the data contained in myUser becomes null...

Comment: Yes, indeed. There is no such thing as "background" on mobile devices. They only keep the illusion of running multiple apps, by keeping a screenshot of all of them. What happens is the app gets booted from memory and restarted when you pick the screenshot. You will need to look into keeping your apps information, even if it gets destroyed.